# sql database deploying

Tags: sql-server

I have never deployed any windows applicatioon,,,this is my first one...

my question is how to deploy a windows application-with sql database on client side..
IF sql server 2005 is installed onclient pc then ..the client doesnt have to do anytihng only run exe file..I think i can do this by attaching it by code...but i also want that the client shouldnt be able to see my database...is it possible to achieve...

I mean to say that can vb.net code write and read from database without attaching it in sql server managemt studio

sorry if my english not good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redistribute SQL Server Express with your application. Read [Embedding SQL Server 2008 Express in an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). All the other editions would have to be provided by your customer and your application, during installation, only requests the location (connection string) to the hosting SQL Server instance. With any option you use, the database will belong to the client and he will be in absolute control of the content.

> but i also want that the client shouldnt be able to see my database

This is **not possible** if you choose to use a database at the client location. Your only option is to host the database and let the client connect remotely to the hosted database. Options are [SQL Azure Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/), host [SQL in an Azure VM](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/), [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) or similar.